# Spring MVC 4: Interceptor not being able to set Response header

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jboss, wildfly

I have a Spring 4 MVC app where I have an interceptor that calculates execution time for the request response cycle and I want to set a header like `X-Runtime` with the value of the execution time. However, the `response.setHeader` function is not working. By the time the response reaches my brower, it is being overridden.

I have a CORS filter where I am setting request and response headers to enables cross origin requests and that works fine.

Here is my interceptor:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class ExecuteTimeInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ExecuteTimeInterceptor.class.getName());

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        LOGGER.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString() + ":: Start Time=" + System.currentTimeMillis());
        request.setAttribute("startTime", startTime);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        Long startTime = (Long) request.getAttribute("startTime");
        Long timeTaken = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        LOGGER.info("Request URL::" + request.getRequestURL().toString() + ":: Time Taken=" + timeTaken);
        response.setHeader("X-Runtime", timeTaken.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // Do nothing.
    }
}
```

I have configured the interceptor correctly in my `dispatcher.xml` config file. The execution time is being logged correctly by `slf4j` so I can confirm the interceptor itself is working correctly.

Any idea why this is happening? I am using WildFly (previously JBoss) 8.1 as my container/app server.

Answer (score 4):

By the time the response hits the `postHandle` method in your `HandlerInterceptor`, the response *may have been committed already*, which means that you can't write response headers anymore.

That's why most of the time this kind of behavior is implemented in a Servlet filter and wraps the response with a caching wrapper. See `ShallowEtagHeaderFilter` and its use of a `ContentCachingResponseWrapper` in Spring.